# Error estimation of a small dataset of counts

Tags: poisson-distribution, bootstrap, count-data, measurement-error

I am pretty sure it will take a few goes for me to phrase this question correctly but hopefully somebody with relevant knowledge will understand. I also hope this question actually has an answer(s) so that it becomes more than a philosophical discussion- I am aiming to be as specific as possible to avoid this. I also apologise if I am repeating previous questions- although this is no doubt a common topic, as a non-statistician it can be difficult to know whether solutions are relevant to your specific case.

So without further ado to my problem:
I have been photographing (still shots) bubbles whilst changing properties of the liquid they reside in. It turns out that the number of bubbles is strongly correlated with one parameter in particular, let us say x. In order to investigate this further I hold the parameter steady and obtain 1 photograph per minute for 1 hour, thus n=60. I then mean the number of bubbles and plot them as a function of x. This seemed to work well- a linear correlation of the mean of the number of bubbles versus parameter x results in an R2 of 0.98. However now to my problem- the random nature of the 1/60 second exposure, 60 times in 1 hour (basically 1/3600 of the time) means that my standard deviation of the number of bubbles is large (~60%). I assumed that the chaotic nature of catching bubbles in my images would mean that if I plot a histogram of the number of bubbles per image it would be roughly Gaussian (if very broad); however it appears to be slightly skewed (I have no physical explanation for this so suspect it be simply the small size of the dataset).

So to my exact question: is a resampling method such as bootstrapping suitable here given that my distribution does not seem physically plausible? Or should I simply take more photos? What kind of a test should I do to estimate how many photos is enough? I have plotted both the mean and standard deviation as a function of the number of photographs and they both appear to stabilise after much less than 60 photos...

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

> I assumed that the chaotic nature of catching bubbles in my images would mean that if I plot a histogram of the number of bubbles per image it would be roughly Gaussian

Maybe, maybe not. My first guess would have been Poisson (which can be approximated as Gaussian if there are "enough" bubbles).

Train of thoughts: one of the famous examples for producing a Poisson distribution is measuring radioactive decay. From a chemical kinetics point of view, that is a first order kinetics. So if the production of your bubbles can sensibly be described or approximated as (pseudo) first order, Poisson distribution would be a sensible assumption.

I'd think that bubble kinetics are somewhat more complicated (there's seeding and growth) but that may be a first start.

Comment: Ah yes of course! I was confused by it being a discrete variable- counts and not continuous. Looking again at the histrograms you can see that as I have more bubbles (by increasing parameter x) my distribution looks more and more Gaussian as the mean shifts to larger counts. Trying to recall some stats now- is the standard deviation of a Poission distribution sqrt(mean)?

Comment: @user1912925: yes.